Understanding EF Core Add-Migration
I tried finding this the source code to investigate how it finds the context but no luck with source code so far.
Here is a my project structure:

EXE App containing EF Core Tools
Class library containing my EF model

I have add a non-default constructor to DbContext to accept options.
When I run add-migration, how does it create the DbContext object?  Why do I need a runnable project (which loads at runtime) to use EF Core tools?
Does add-migration load the exe and try to create the instance of the DbContext from it? It seems like it even uses the services registration in the host exe.
Any pointers or explanations will be immensely helpful.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/internals/tools#creating-a-dbcontext

Please see [ask]. Ask one pointed question, preferably containing a [mre], when posting questions on Stack Overflow.
